# JS for item in items -> promise chain gets wrong values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, teamspeak

I can't grasp how to get the correct value. Blow my problem.

So for example i sometimes get the clientlist which does not contain two of the same people ever. Then for each of them i want to add another promise where i pass the name of each. Problem is that sometimes i get two called "Foo" and "Foo", instead of "Foo" and "Bar".

```
(...)    
for (let client in clients) {

   chain = chain.then(resolve => mainEvent(clients[client])) // since this is built and executed after, I sometimes get repeating client names. It's really unpredictable and weird.

   ev.client.chat(clients[client].name()) // correct output but this is in sync with the loop
}
(...)
```

Comment: `let client in clients`  did you mean `let client of clients`

Comment: @Keith dosn't really matter for the example. I am not getting the right client names. 

Since the for loop is not synchronous and they all execute the same time and build the promise chain, i get the wrong names from time to time.  and i'm not sure how to make sure that i get the correct ones.

Comment: is `clients` an array or an object ?

Comment: Ah right, in that cast you can use a `reduce` to create a promise chain -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708437/how-to-properly-chain-promises-using-reduce,  but personally I'd go for `async / await` if at all possible.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli if i'm right it is an Object. Why is that relevant? (i'd check but i am not at the desktop right now)

Comment: because if it is an array then the `client` holds the index of the array and if you access the `clients` by index and the `clients` has changed you get wrong results.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli i'll check if it's an array.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli It's an Object. Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: What is `mainEvent`, and what are you doing with `clients` afterwards?

Comment: @Bergi well it does loads of stuff. In short it's making a bunch of API calls.
But when i test "client.name()" i don't always get the correct client name logged to the console. So that is what should work first. Imagine there is just a console.log() in there.

Comment: @Frizzant With just a console.log in there, and no other code, the snippet you posted *does work*. There must be something in the code manipulating `clients` or the individual client objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of `clients` change while your program is executing, that could be your problem. Since the `for in` loop is making a reference to the keys but not the values, and `clients[client]` is evaluated at a later point in time because of the promise chain.

You have two options: either switch to a `for of` loop to get the values of the object instead of the keys, or add a `const value = clients[client]` inside the body of the loop and use `value` in your closures. Both of these methods will retrieve the values at the time of the loop's execution, which is what you want.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out what you are explaining in the second part.
First I'll see if `for of` works. I'll be testing tomorrow.

Comment: From my test it seems to have fixed it. However I'll have to see if that persists. So i'll accept this in a week or so. Thanks alot !